# jq: filter out IP addresses by regular expression

Tags: jq

```
[
      {
        "arguments": {
          "leases": [
            {
              "cltt": 1658763299,
              "fqdn-fwd": false,
              "fqdn-rev": false,
              "hostname": "",
              "hw-address": "00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee",
              "ip-address": "192.168.0.2",
              "state": 0,
              "subnet-id": 1,
              "valid-lft": 3600
            },
            {
              "cltt": 1658763207,
              "fqdn-fwd": false,
              "fqdn-rev": false,
              "hostname": "",
              "hw-address": "00:11:22:33:44:55",
              "ip-address": "192.168.1.3",
              "state": 0,
              "subnet-id": 1,
              "valid-lft": 3600
            }
          ]
        },
        "result": 0,
        "text": "2 IPv4 lease(s) found."
      }
    ]
```

This is a snippet, but in reality there's much more entries. Currently I filter out MAC and IP with `jq` expression:

```
jq --raw-output '.[0] | select(.result == 0) | .arguments.leases[] | "\(.["hw-address"]) \(.["ip-address"])"'
```

Now I'm wondering: does `jq` have ability to filter out by regexp? For instance I'd like to dump only entries where IP is `192.168.1.*`, can it be done with jq? Ideally I'd like to pass regexp to my script as a parameter:

```
jq --raw-output --arg addr "$1" ...
```

Would appreciate suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq has [`test`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#test(val),test(regex;flags)) to test an input against a regular expression:

```
first
| select(.result == 0)
| .arguments.leases[]
| select(."ip-address"|test("^192\\.168\\.1"))
| "\(."hw-address") \(."ip-address")"
```

and to provide the regex as argument via command line:

```
jq -r --arg regex '^192\.168\.1\.' 'first
| select(.result == 0)
| .arguments.leases[]
| select(."ip-address"|test($regex))
| "\(."hw-address") \(."ip-address")"'
```

*If* you only want to check the start of the IP address, you could also use [`startswith`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#startswith(str)): `select(."ip-address"|startswith("192.168.1."))`:

```
jq -r --arg prefix '192.168.1.' 'first
| select(.result == 0)
| .arguments.leases[]
| select(."ip-address"|startswith($prefix))
| "\(."hw-address") \(."ip-address")"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `test` with regular expressions, and `select` to filter:

```bash
jq -r --arg addr "192\\.168\\.1\\..*" '
  .[0] | select(.result == 0) | .arguments.leases[]
  | "\(.["hw-address"]) \(.["ip-address"] | select(test($addr)))"
'
```

```
00:11:22:33:44:55 192.168.1.3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MAngJ_gDIlD)

Note: `192.168.1.*` is not a regular expression (or at least not one you want to use, as it would also match `192.168.100.4` for instance, because `.` stands for any value; a literal dot has to be escaped)